# Are there any benevolent warp beings who help the Imperium?

Tags: warhammer-40k

I know the warp houses all the psychic and emotional energy created by all the psychic races in the galaxy, and that energy taken to the extreme by the nature of the warp caused the emergence of all the daemon, dark gods and other warp entities that plague the galaxy.

But what about benevolent entities? Beings shaped in the warped by the more positive emotions the races posses. It is theorized that the Sanguinor is one such entity of the warp, that helps the blood angels in times of dire needs. And is thought to be the embodiment of the emotional and spiritual need of the chapter's desire to see their Primarch reborn. But what about other long dead primarchs or even the Emperor? Surely the belief and adoration of the Imperium towards the Emperor would have some impact on the warp.

Comment: From how I always understood it (as no facts there I'm using it not as an answer but as a comment instead) there WERE before the great war but then when "chaos" rised during the war these beings were absorbed by the later chaos deities

Comment: There were the Eldar gods, some of them were destroyed and a few survived (Isha being an example of a benevolent Eldar goddess). And there's also Gork and Mork. but my question is more targeted towards beings made by the emotional impact of humans on the warp

Comment: I also thought about the eldar gods there BUT one of the books (blood ravens books) indicates that these "gods" may be nothing more than heroes of the eldar (it is only implied in the book which has information about the black archive (or how it is called))

Comment: @svarog: I can't remember any source telling that Eldars gods were Warp entities.

Comment: @Thomas: what is the "great war" you are speaking about?

Comment: @Taldaris the war between the old ones (first ones?) and the necrons. The great war was between those two and saw the creation of many species including the eldar. Back then the warp was not as it is today, but the death of many psykers (billioins?) in that war created ripples in the sea of souls and led to the creation of chaos. There are mentionings of this in the necron army books (of the different versions of that book)

Comment: One of the new Tau fluff books mentions that a warp being of the Greater Good. Created by humans who have joined the Tau believing in it as if it were a being. It showed up and saved the Tau fleet from the other deamons. I have no references though, so am not posting as an answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, if you are thinking of immaterium creatures that never been corporeal (like gods and demons) that would be bening to humans the answer is "not likely" - the war between Old Ones and Necrons/C'than turned Warp into hell, birth of Slaanesh that wiped almost all Eldar gods (which wouldn't be too nice to humans either) also didn't help.  But there are few beings that have been turned into immaterial form and are supporting the Empire:

Saints are the most prominent example: even when they die they can influence lives of mortals - dead [Saint Sabbat](http://warhammer40k.wikia.com/wiki/Saint_Sabbat) was guiding at least one pilgrim to her resting place in "Honour Guard". And then she got better and inhabited (possessed?) the bodies of at least two girls.

Another example is the [Legion of the Damned](http://warhammer40k.wikia.com/wiki/Legion_of_the_Damned) which while being originally normal Space Marines now behave similar to vengeful wraiths - they can turn invisible, apparently walk through walls (ok most Marines can do that... but I mean without destroying them!) and be night invulnerable to the normal damage.

When it comes to representation of dead primarchs then FOR SURE only Sanguinus is truly dead: Guilliman is mortally wounded, Ferrus Manus is apparently in eternal 'resurrected-"Join us!" offer-killed' cycle held by Fulgrim, Dorn and Vulcan are missing and only presumed dead, rest is simply missing/asleep, so they can't help their sons "from the other side".

EDIT: Well, there is also [Malal/Malice](http://warhammer40k.wikia.com/wiki/Malal) which could support the Empire as an "enemy of my enemy" but its not likely. Also he is not exactly canon...

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about the other Primarchs but as far as the Emperor is concerned there are the Star Child Prophecies. http://warhammer40k.wikia.com/wiki/The_Emperor_of_Mankind#The_Star_Child

Though the Star Child prophecies are forbidden by order of the inquisition.

Answer (score 0):

No not of my knowledge but there eventually might be some. When the emperor died and rips a new one in the Sol system and grows in the warp he will have like angles and angle princes like the exact mirrors of chaos entities. If he doesn't ascend and just comes back then ehh. Also there is Malice the 5th god of chaos he represents chaos tendency to turn on its self and acts against the other gods every chance he gets but he also is no friend of humanity.

Answer (score 0):

Examples of warp beings that actively seek to help the Imperium are humans that turn into the form of saints, astartes into the legion of damned, sanguinor, Emperor summoned ferrus soul and other brave souls once to defend the warp gate.

There is the concept of "warp human heaven with angelic beings" to aid the Imperium but likely not see it to be strong canon material any time.

Prominent old fluff warp creatures are enslavers swarm, void whales, furies & the denizens of engine forge. Some warp creatures have permanent forms to access our reality without requirement of excess warp energy, but those are the days of war in heaven.

These creatures harm humans and daemons as well.

From small description of chaos wasteland, there are "new creatures" of warp popping out here and there, due to concentrate emotional thoughts that fit none of the scope of 4 chaos gods (which is incredible)

Although they had to survive hellish warp, but current material suggests they do carve a section of it and turn into their domains; influence is minor due to way lesser emotional energy. Assume a sub-sector amount of humans had very specific positive belief and superstition for thousand years, and there it goes.